# Python entry to store input into a variable stores nothing, returns initial value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Ok, so basic story. I have created an entry. After you introduce text, you have to click a button to store the inputted text into a variable that is later printed.
Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import * 

def myClick(entry_name, var):#defines function to get input from entry and store into var
   var = entry_name.get()

root = Tk()#creates initial tk

lbl1 = Label(root, text = "hello")#before entry label
lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)#label griding

ent = Entry(root, width = 15)# the entry
ent.grid(row = 1, column = 0)#entry gridding

hello = None #variable to store entry input
bt1 = Button(root, command = myClick(ent, hello))#button 1 creation and function attribution
bt1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)#button 1 griding

root.mainloop()
print(hello)
```

It is very unclear to me why the function does not get the input from the entry.

Answer (score 0):

just define a normal function :

```
from tkinter import * 

def blinta():
    var = ent.get()
    ent.delete(0,END)
    print(var)
root = Tk()#creates initial tk

lbl1 = Label(root, text = "hello")#before entry label
lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)#label griding

ent = Entry(root, width = 15)# the entry
ent.grid(row = 1, column = 0)#entry gridding
bt1 = Button(root, command = blinta)
bt1.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

This will work I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
bt1 = Button(root, command = myClick(ent, hello))
```

In this line, you call myClick function with parameters, not just pass it. That means that myClick is executed once after the module is launched and then it does nothing. If you want to print the entry input, I recommend you do the following:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

lbl1 = Label(root, text="hello")
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0)

ent = Entry(root, width=15)
ent.grid(row=1, column=0)


def myClick():
    var = ent.get()
    print(var)


bt1 = Button(root, command=myClick)
bt1.grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Also code after root.mainloop() doesn't excecute.

Comment: But after root.mailoop(), the variable var will still have the input assigned value? That's kind of the main point of storing into the variable... The print() is to check if it was assigned...

Comment: @alex, code after root.mainloop() don't execute but don't think about it as the end of the program. It prevents the window from instantly closing and you can have things like an infinite loop before it running forever. If I understand you correctly, the example I provided above does exactly what you want. You can enter the text into the entry field any time and check if the variable was reassigned by pressing the button.

Comment: I need to store the entry input data assigned to var in the myClick function into a global variable, for example, hello, the was defined earlier.

Comment: @alex, initialize the ```var``` variable before defining myClick function (```var = None```) and access it there via ```global``` (add ```global var``` at the beginning of the function definition.

Comment: Yes, this might work but I need to use this function with multiple global variables and I am not going to define the function for every variable. I need the function argument that takes the name of the variable to store the entry input given string in the actual global variable, without to acces it in the function with 'global var'...